# Time tracker in R

Tags: r

I was wondering how to calculate the time difference in R.
What I want to do is write a for loop that sums the difference in two times in a sequence. My time values are:

```
class(time_tracker[["Time"]])
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

I have this code here that throws an Error: Column index must be at most 1 if positive, not 2.

```
time_diff <- vector(length = nrow(time_tracker) / 2)
for (ii in 1:nrow(time_tracker)) {
  if (ii %% 2 == 1) {
    time_diff[ii] <- 0
    next
  }
  time_diff[ii] <- time_tracker[ii] - time_tracker[ii-1]
}
```

EDIT: I am attaching the results of dput(time_tracker)

```
> dput(time_tracker)
structure(list(Time = structure(c(1514816115.47, 1514830259.635, 
1514902914.733, 1514914080.377, 1514985907.22, 1514991852.622, 
1515074871.862, 1515083693.884, 1515157263.375, 1515164762.199, 
1515171659.051, 1515178817.472, 1515412548.314, 1515421898.408, 
1515426894.401, 1515432378.804, 1515510162.063, 1515521213.24, 
1515587687.496, 1515592079.084, 1515596566.348, 1515601214.072, 
1515669624.922, 1515674005.052, 1515678130.703, 1515683168.14, 
1515693012.189, 1515702965.051, 1515766180.92, 1515777198.981, 
1516120746.324, 1516123811.672, 1516378829.789, 1516383306.033, 
1516454060.532, 1516460219.87, 1516628714.27, 1516631433.181, 
1516836119.135, 1516840996.022, 1516979800.66, 1516982200.996, 
1517071285.444, 1517074935.673), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-44L), .Names = "Time")
```

Comment: Should your for loop be looping over `nrow(time_tracker)` when `time_diff` is only half that length?

Comment: could you provide some data?

Comment: `dput(time_tracker)`  and share output with us.

Comment: @akash87  data is up

Comment: you haven't selected a column of the data frame `time_tracker` (even though there is only one to select from) `time_diff[ii] <- time_tracker[ii] - time_tracker[ii-1]` should be `time_diff[ii] <- time_tracker[ii, ] - time_tracker[ii-1, ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing the typo in order to select a column, your code above will create a vector with something like `c(time2 - time1, 0, time4 - time3, 0, time6 - time5, ...)` etc. Is this what you are looking for?

If you are looking for the time difference between each consecutive time it would be easier to use something like `diff(time_tracker[ ,1], lag = 1)`

Comment: When I do run diff(time_tracker[, 1], lag = 1), I get a tibble with o rows...nothing back. Perhaps this is because my times are in POSIXct ; POSIXt format?

Comment: `diff()` specifically has a method for class "POSIXt" so I don't think this is causing the problem. I actually cut and pasted from your comment and your `dput()` output and it worked for me. You could specify the method by using `diff.POSIXt()` although this is technically the same function or you could try `time_tracker[2:n,] - time_tracker[1:(n-1),]` (n = 44 in this case) which is essentially what `diff(x, lag = 1)` is doing.

Comment: I tried `diff.POSIXt(time_tracker[ ,1], lag = 1)` and now it gives me `Time difference of  secs` so I think R is picking up the class of the times, but is not giving me the number of seconds...